# Plot f(x),f(y),alpha where f(x) and f(y) are the solutions of a two ODEs system depending on a parameter α

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

My question is in the title.
For example, the system could be:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{dx}{dt}&=-y+x[\alpha-(x^2+y^2)]\\\frac{dy}{dt}&=x+y[\alpha-(x^2+y^2)]\end{align*}$$

And I want to plot this :

[image: plot]

For example with `{t, 0, 10}` and `{α, -10, 10, 2}`.

I begin to try some experiments, but it seems to be too much difficult for the beginner I am.
So, thank you for your educational help.

Pascal77

Comment: Please post your code instead of picture.

Comment: My code is not available. Sorry.

Comment: By $f(x)$ do you mean $x(t)$, or is there another function $f$?  The image looks like you wish to plot $(x(t), y(t))$.

Answer (score 5):

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == -y[t] + 
      x[t] (α - (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)), 
    D[y[t], t] == x[t] + y[t] (α - (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)), 
    x[0] == a, y[0] == b}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, α}];
{x0, y0} = {1, 1};
ParametricPlot3D[
 Table[{x[x0, y0, α][t], α, y[x0, y0, α][t]} /. 
   sol, {α, -10, 10, 2}], {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, α, y}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull!
I tried on my own side with ParametricPlot3D but unsuccessfully. I was lost with the Table used in your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I just modified  2 little things : 

I added : "PlotRange-> All"
I replaced "LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]" by "LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]"

Comment: I just want to say that this help website is amazing!
I snoop in on it very often, and I always discover some astounding solutions, very original ones, with a big touch of class.
So congratulations to all specialists which, cvgmt, you belong.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that is a little non-precise mathematically but maybe more aesthetic:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == -y[t] + x[t] (α[t] - (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)), 
  y'[t] == x[t] + y[t] (α[t] - (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)),
  α'[t] == -0.1,
  x[-50] == 1, y[-50] == 1, α[-50] == 25}, {x, y, α}, {t, 0, 400}][[1]];
ParametricPlot3D[{α[t], x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 400}, AxesLabel -> {α, x, y}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Indeed, it is very smooth.
It is another approach with alpha considered as a variable, in fact.
Interesting.